# Dynamic subsetting of dataframe by the contents of another

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dynamic dataframe of the top 5 'events' over the last year; produced by performing: head(source_df, 5). This produces a dataframe of the following structure:

```
top_5  <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1670284800, 1669852800, 
1669161600, 1668470400, 1668470400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Name = c("lt 20", 
"lt 201", "lt 45", "lt 212", 
"lt 01"),
    Volume = c(3252, 2511.221, 
    3559.5, 3250, 2250), Amount = c(2.1, 2.4, 
    1.21, 1.44, 6.12), AAP = c(3.472214, 
    3.411409, 3.346509, 3.425947, 3.591546), Code= c("C7720", "Z8158", 
    "K7110", "Z2138", "G7751")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a number of huge dataframes that cover various transactions in these codes.
What I would like to do is dynamically create 5 subsetted dataframes (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5) for each of the codes in the above dataframe. Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this? Apologies for any issue, English is not a first language.

As request, here is a portion of dput:

```
df <- structure(list(Code = c("CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", 
"C7720", "CK1204", "C7720", "CK1204", "CK1204", "C7720", "C7720", 
"C7720", "C7720", "CK1204", "C7720"), created_date = structure(c(1665648152, 
1665648158, 1665659232, 1665659242, 1665659251, 1665659252, 1665659253, 
1665669818, 1665669821, 1665669824, 1665675909, 1665678402, 1665730532, 
1665730557, 1665730557, 1665730658, 1665732786, 1665732799, 1665733243, 
1665735272, 1665735539, 1665736772, 1665738161, 1665738162, 1665738163, 
1665738844, 1665740917, 1665741969, 1665752537, 1665761590, 1665993764, 
1665994115, 1665995443, 1665996642, 1666000592, 1666000618, 1666023627, 
1666077837, 1666077840, 1666077840, 1666078233, 1666078244, 1666079323, 
1666079424, 1666079592, 1666081830, 1666082531, 1666083527, 1666083684, 
1666085306, 1666085307, 1666085308, 1666085308, 1666096369, 1666165196, 
1666165208, 1666166681, 1666166794, 1666167309, 1666167700, 1666169296, 
1666169773, 1666169888, 1666170107, 1666171340, 1666179630, 1666187378, 
1666187379, 1666187382, 1666251885, 1666254899, 1666254903, 1666255923, 
1666255923, 1666256216, 1666258252, 1666258255, 1666258266, 1666260784, 
1666260786, 1666266370, 1666282551, 1666282552, 1666282553, 1666282553, 
1666337321, 1666337321, 1666338405, 1666338409, 1666338410, 1666338412, 
1666338414, 1666339297, 1666340555, 1666340560, 1666340560, 1666340560, 
1666341337, 1666341342, 1666341342, 1666341646, 1666343764, 1666343819, 
1666343822, 1666348703, 1666348704, 1666348705, 1666348713, 1666597423, 
1666597846, 1666598453, 1666599461, 1666599464, 1666600182, 1666600189, 
1666600944, 1666601297, 1666602821, 1666604877, 1666605403, 1666606271, 
1666606854, 1666607956, 1666607959, 1666622108, 1666627412, 1666683967, 
1666684016, 1666684533, 1666686088, 1666686392, 1666687135, 1666687137, 
1666687324, 1666690920, 1666693504, 1666694374, 1666698401, 1666717757, 
1666769576, 1666769594, 1666769832, 1666770004, 1666770221, 1666770275, 
1666770275, 1666770601, 1666770969, 1666775072, 1666775271, 1666855021, 
1666856413, 1666860314, 1666860315, 1666860317, 1666860318, 1666860319, 
1666860320, 1666861307, 1666861480, 1666861525, 1666861587, 1666866119, 
1666866262, 1666866996, 1666870087, 1666870093, 1666890419, 1666942353, 
1666942355, 1666943062, 1666943518, 1666943558, 1666943736, 1666943854, 
1666945798, 1666946105, 1666948598, 1666950225, 1666962199, 1666962564, 
1666972042, 1667200485, 1667200489, 1667201538, 1667201538, 1667201550, 
1667201550, 1667202087, 1667202094, 1667202940, 1667204160, 1667206317, 
1667206317, 1667206319, 1667206321, 1667206322, 1667206329, 1667206823, 
1667207094, 1667207285, 1667210155, 1667211720, 1667214158, 1667214158, 
1667214158, 1667214162, 1667214162, 1667214172, 1667214172, 1667219532, 
1667227480, 1667231544, 1667231548, 1667286815, 1667288344, 1667288344, 
1667288526, 1667288763, 1667289691, 1667290883, 1667290899, 1667290899, 
1667291193, 1667291552, 1667292537, 1667293882, 1667293882, 1667297509, 
1667297509, 1667297512, 1667297526, 1667297526, 1667297528, 1667297562, 
1667310644, 1667318983, 1667319255, 1667321535, 1667376540, 1667377020, 
1667377023, 1667377320, 1667377320, 1667377431, 1667377436, 1667377436, 
1667377441, 1667377441, 1667377508, 1667377508, 1667377530, 1667377530, 
1667377632, 1667377637, 1667377640, 1667378756, 1667379292, 1667381932, 
1667382098, 1667383621, 1667384112, 1667386434, 1667396849, 1667397993, 
1667398183, 1667406911, 1667460369, 1667460743, 1667462319, 1667462319, 
1667462319, 1667462770, 1667464205, 1667464237, 1667464737, 1667464741, 
1667464741, 1667464741, 1667464741, 1667464741, 1667464741, 1667468132, 
1667468140, 1667468140, 1667468622, 1667468654, 1667469023, 1667470267, 
1667473338, 1667484332, 1667484332, 1667486381, 1667487021, 1667487099, 
1667487099, 1667487115, 1667487115, 1667487226, 1667488216, 1667488229, 
1667492365, 1667492369, 1667494230, 1667544688, 1667545642, 1667545642, 
1667546201, 1667546224, 1667546227, 1667546229, 1667548038, 1667548954, 
1667548958, 1667548958, 1667549546, 1667549546, 1667550057, 1667550057, 
1667551249, 1667551249, 1667551249, 1667551249, 1667553391, 1667553391, 
1667553391, 1667554964, 1667554964, 1667555308, 1667562224, 1667562224, 
1667562224, 1667565578, 1667565580, 1667565580, 1667565580, 1667565581, 
1667565581, 1667566223, 1667566224, 1667566225, 1667566226, 1667566229, 
1667568922, 1667571775, 1667573810, 1667576872, 1667578294, 1667580587, 
1667803625, 1667804580, 1667804694, 1667805044, 1667806431, 1667806844, 
1667806845, 1667806845, 1667806845, 1667806845, 1667806849, 1667806855, 
1667806855, 1667806855, 1667806855, 1667807039, 1667807281, 1667807286, 
1667807286, 1667808698, 1667808710, 1667809402, 1667810034, 1667810209, 
1667810212, 1667810498, 1667810502, 1667810502, 1667811984, 1667811984, 
1667811986, 1667811988, 1667811989, 1667812052, 1667813410, 1667818484, 
1667818484, 1667818484, 1667818672, 1667818672, 1667823977, 1667823982, 
1667825766, 1667825766, 1667825766, 1667834700, 1667834706, 1667891311, 
1667891413, 1667891415, 1667891417, 1667891425, 1667891603, 1667892181, 
1667892191, 1667892381, 1667893317, 1667893317, 1667893320, 1667893528, 
1667894914, 1667895763, 1667895770, 1667895770, 1667896557, 1667900431, 
1667902493, 1667902765, 1667902812, 1667902824, 1667902829, 1667902837, 
1667903416, 1667904504, 1667904505, 1667904506, 1667907454, 1667909259, 
1667909433, 1667916549, 1667916549, 1667919949, 1667919949, 1667919949, 
1667921719, 1667924253, 1667924254, 1667924958, 1667925056, 1667926265, 
1667978320, 1667980092, 1667980092, 1667980402, 1667980402, 1667980547, 
1667980551, 1667981245, 1667981245, 1667981245, 1667981245, 1667981254, 
1667981258, 1667981258, 1667981275, 1667982875, 1667982882, 1667983066, 
1667984077, 1667984078, 1667984079, 1667984080, 1667984080, 1667984641, 
1667984645, 1667984645, 1667984645, 1667984825, 1667986231, 1667986236, 
1667987283, 1667996194, 1667998660, 1667998668, 1667999706, 1667999706, 
1667999710, 1667999710, 1668003316, 1668003607, 1668004628, 1668008021, 
1668008021, 1668008528, 1668008528, 1668008528, 1668008528, 1668008769, 
1668009889, 1668010101, 1668011365, 1668012950, 1668064515, 1668065545, 
1668066587, 1668067471, 1668067471, 1668067471, 1668067483, 1668067493, 
1668068723, 1668069072, 1668069967, 1668069968, 1668069977, 1668069978, 
1668069981, 1668069983, 1668070023, 1668071160, 1668072141, 1668072141, 
1668073494, 1668075105, 1668075706, 1668075707, 1668075708, 1668075710, 
1668075713, 1668077628, 1668085739, 1668085741, 1668096393, 1668096393, 
1668149395, 1668153260, 1668154237, 1668156235, 1668156235, 1668157012, 
1668157147, 1668157332, 1668167339, 1668167339, 1668170529, 1668413110, 
1668414754, 1668415865, 1668416072, 1668416902, 1668417181, 1668417185, 
1668420061, 1668420063, 1668420505, 1668423159, 1668424535, 1668424536, 
1668424539, 1668442856, 1668442857, 1668442857, 1668442858, 1668442859, 
1668442861, 1668443364, 1668443928, 1668497726, 1668505114, 1668505114, 
1668505500, 1668506072, 1668506072, 1668507689, 1668517854, 1668517855, 
1668519266, 1668522565, 1668522647, 1668529177, 1668581733, 1668582998, 
1668584740, 1668584796, 1668584804, 1668584982, 1668585802, 1668589701, 
1668589701, 1668589873, 1668589879, 1668591811, 1668592099, 1668592099, 
1668596905, 1668596909, 1668596913, 1668596913, 1668605401, 1668605401, 
1668607548, 1668607560, 1668607567, 1668607592, 1668668093, 1668672420, 
1668673103, 1668673440, 1668673916, 1668673916, 1668673916, 1668673916, 
1668673927, 1668673927, 1668679742, 1668679844, 1668679996, 1668686025, 
1668686025, 1668686029, 1668686030, 1668686033, 1668686035, 1668701135, 
1668701146, 1668701150, 1668755601, 1668760627, 1668760627, 1668760627, 
1668761290, 1668762519, 1668770870, 1668770885, 1668770925, 1668770941, 
1668773335, 1668773345, 1668780842, 1669015665, 1669016645, 1669016645, 
1669019633, 1669019633, 1669019633, 1669019635, 1669019636, 1669019637, 
1669019637, 1669019641, 1669019644, 1669020014, 1669020014, 1669023279, 
1669023306, 1669023340, 1669045748, 1669046718, 1669046719, 1669046721, 
1669046740, 1669046869, 1669104172, 1669105613, 1669105613, 1669105613, 
1669105615, 1669105615, 1669105616, 1669105616, 1669106551, 1669106561, 
1669106561, 1669106562, 1669106562, 1669106571, 1669106571, 1669127456, 
1669127509, 1669131960, 1669131960, 1669132073, 1669132112, 1669137144, 
1669187743, 1669187743, 1669189055, 1669192137, 1669192137, 1669192137, 
1669199126, 1669199288, 1669212237, 1669212241, 1669212241, 1669217964, 
1669217965, 1669217966, 1669217967, 1669217971, 1669217980, 1669275749, 
1669275930, 1669275930, 1669275930, 1669277152, 1669277152, 1669277152, 
1669277153, 1669277240, 1669283770, 1669288792, 1669361473, 1669361957, 
1669362044, 1669362078, 1669362078, 1669362078, 1669362164, 1669362183, 
1669363788, 1669363788, 1669363788, 1669363788, 1669363788, 1669363788, 
1669363788, 1669363788, 1669363796, 1669363796, 1669363796, 1669369720, 
1669374472, 1669374769, 1669384355, 1669384356, 1669384357, 1669384358, 
1669384359, 1669394535, 1669621688, 1669621688, 1669621919, 1669621919, 
1669621984, 1669623710, 1669623790, 1669624502, 1669631566, 1669631568, 
1669636034, 1669636319, 1669648542, 1669649429, 1669705560, 1669708245, 
1669708253, 1669709201, 1669709201, 1669709201, 1669710009, 1669710013, 
1669728157, 1669728157, 1669728158, 1669728158, 1669729113, 1669731123, 
1669735618, 1669735622, 1669735655, 1669792519, 1669792519, 1669792687, 
1669793685, 1669793685, 1669793689, 1669795433, 1669795555, 1669795568, 
1669797843, 1669797890, 1669800804, 1669802361, 1669803951, 1669803951, 
1669812329, 1669823547, 1669878606, 1669879411, 1669879504, 1669879525, 
1669880945, 1669881538, 1669881538, 1669881785, 1669881791, 1669881967, 
1669881967, 1669881997, 1669882798, 1669886097, 1669893425, 1669893425, 
1669893425, 1669893432, 1669893432, 1669893432, 1669894181, 1669895088, 
1669898383, 1669900645, 1669900645, 1669901390, 1669901978, 1669905313, 
1669908785, 1669911665, 1669912944, 1669914474, 1669914474, 1669965802, 
1669967824, 1669967824, 1669967824, 1669968681, 1669972570, 1669972571, 
1669972572, 1669972695, 1669973475, 1669973629, 1669973633, 1669973907, 
1669973912, 1669985457, 1669985459, 1669985459, 1669985459, 1669985459, 
1669985459, 1669988227, 1669988227, 1669990749, 1669992593, 1669992601, 
1670000320, 1670000320, 1670000321, 1670000321, 1670000324, 1670000472, 
1670000472, 1670001039, 1670223647, 1670223647, 1670226128, 1670226720, 
1670227647, 1670227647, 1670228798, 1670228798, 1670228941, 1670228941, 
1670228943, 1670228943, 1670228945, 1670228945, 1670228946, 1670228946, 
1670230164, 1670231490, 1670237010, 1670237010, 1670250864, 1670253784, 
1670254814, 1670258111, 1670258111, 1670258117, 1670259376, 1670259376, 
1670260039, 1670260040, 1670310866, 1670310870, 1670311438, 1670311653, 
1670314066, 1670314097, 1670317614, 1670318798, 1670324910, 1670328627
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), quantity = c(0.1, 
0.045, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.02, 0.045, 0.045, 0.043, 
0.001, 0.024, 0.012, 0.056, 0.012, 0.07, 0.111, 0.119, 0.012, 
0.015, 0.012, 0.005, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.007, 0.054, 
0.054, 0.012, 0.101, 0.003, 0.031, 0.025, 0.04, 0.085, 0.04, 
0.009, 0.028, 0.003, 0.025, 0.015, 0.025, 0.001, 0.09, 0.06, 
0.006, 0.023, 0.017, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.034, 0.095, 0.023, 
0.024, 0.025, 0.04, 0.003, 0.05, 0.048, 0.025, 0.048, 0.001, 
0.001, 0.025, 0.025, 0.008, 0.1, 0.018, 0.016, 0.016, 0.009, 
0.001, 0.008, 0.046, 0.02, 0.015, 0.033, 0.049, 0.018, 0.018, 
0.018, 0.018, 0.036, 0.028, 0.009, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 
0.001, 0.2, 0.002, 0.055, 0.01, 0.149, 0.002, 0.001, 0.016, 0.001, 
0.021, 0.027, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 
0.002, 0.001, 0.033, 0.164, 0.054, 0.005, 0.043, 0.002, 0.005, 
0.039, 0.011, 0.2, 0.072, 0.003, 0.036, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.2, 
0.001, 0.021, 0.018, 0.001, 0.038, 0.048, 0.002, 0.041, 0.3, 
0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.036, 0.006, 0.053, 0.001, 0.2, 0.058, 
0.048, 0.05, 0.001, 0.002, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.02, 
0.009, 0.02, 0.011, 0.039, 0.014, 0.009, 0.055, 0.01, 0.121, 
0.071, 0.015, 0.015, 0.002, 0.007, 0.034, 0.001, 0.036, 0.001, 
0.017, 0.047, 0.132, 0.005, 0.009, 0.086, 0.052, 0.002, 0.001, 
0.023, 0.002, 0.022, 0.021, 0.021, 0.001, 0.022, 0.002, 0.013, 
0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.009, 0.001, 0.01, 
0.057, 0.094, 0.049, 0.189, 0.011, 0.084, 0.04, 0.035, 0.011, 
0.039, 0.011, 0.007, 0.062, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.015, 0.002, 
0.046, 0.048, 0.015, 0.009, 0.012, 0.006, 0.044, 0.172, 0.018, 
0.09, 0.162, 0.163, 0.09, 0.094, 0.015, 0.011, 0.027, 0.04, 0.104, 
0.002, 0.009, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.039, 0.018, 0.035, 
0.015, 0.009, 0.03, 0.007, 0.048, 0.07, 0.05, 0.083, 0.018, 0.012, 
0.009, 0.046, 0.038, 0.112, 0.05, 0.008, 0.002, 0.001, 0.043, 
0.015, 0.025, 0.016, 0.038, 0.034, 0.008, 0.002, 0.006, 0.002, 
0.023, 0.011, 0.045, 0.003, 0.015, 0.005, 0.001, 0.027, 0.001, 
0.005, 0.008, 0.038, 0.076, 0.012, 0.001, 0.017, 0.009, 0.034, 
0.004, 0.002, 0.021, 0.021, 0.016, 0.003, 0.005, 0.003, 0.008, 
0.1, 0.046, 0.04, 0.01, 0.005, 0.004, 0.1, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 
0.02, 0.049, 0.049, 0.103, 0.013, 0.015, 0.048, 0.024, 0.02, 
0.037, 0.009, 0.043, 0.02, 0.037, 0.003, 0.012, 0.002, 0.048, 
0.003, 0.006, 0.011, 0.001, 0.001, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 
0.004, 0.002, 0.035, 0.045, 0.045, 0.026, 0.045, 0.013, 0.033, 
0.005, 0.004, 0.012, 0.046, 0.006, 0.02, 0.151, 0.056, 0.02, 
0.134, 0.019, 0.018, 0.038, 0.001, 0.02, 0.015, 0.035, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.03, 0.003, 0.02, 0.004, 0.02, 0.041, 0.008, 0.02, 0.001, 
0.021, 0.021, 0.017, 0.003, 0.012, 0.001, 0.001, 0.025, 0.007, 
0.028, 0.025, 0.023, 0.012, 0.024, 0.001, 0.024, 0.025, 0.044, 
0.01, 0.005, 0.004, 0.019, 0.025, 0.1, 0.109, 0.054, 0.031, 0.095, 
0.036, 0.001, 0.065, 0.097, 0.094, 0.006, 0.003, 0.012, 0.002, 
0.124, 0.004, 0.015, 0.015, 0.004, 0.054, 0.036, 0.036, 0.017, 
0.029, 0.024, 0.014, 0.006, 0.034, 0.068, 0.317, 0.042, 0.017, 
0.014, 0.013, 0.033, 0.001, 0.025, 0.013, 0.024, 0.016, 0.011, 
0.089, 0.039, 0.015, 0.068, 0.06, 0.015, 0.026, 0.021, 0.026, 
0.015, 0.018, 0.015, 0.005, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.01, 0.003, 0.01, 0.024, 0.025, 0.1, 0.05, 0.035, 0.031, 0.015, 
0.005, 0.015, 0.003, 0.003, 0.034, 0.021, 0.005, 0.04, 0.001, 
0.035, 0.043, 0.005, 0.037, 0.089, 0.059, 0.068, 0.001, 0.002, 
0.05, 0.013, 0.02, 0.001, 0.015, 0.016, 0.031, 0.038, 0.07, 0.011, 
0.041, 0.01, 0.002, 0.024, 0.024, 0.016, 0.008, 0.01, 0.026, 
0.004, 0.125, 0.007, 0.008, 0.018, 0.018, 0.018, 0.018, 0.015, 
0.001, 0.037, 0.035, 0.016, 0.117, 0.013, 0.07, 0.066, 0.046, 
0.083, 0.009, 0.025, 0.025, 0.018, 0.032, 0.034, 0.002, 0.001, 
0.035, 0.025, 0.075, 0.006, 0.012, 0.112, 0.012, 0.025, 0.008, 
0.015, 0.015, 0.005, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 0.001, 0.013, 
0.005, 0.008, 0.013, 0.003, 0.112, 0.029, 0.036, 0.017, 0.026, 
0.035, 0.035, 0.05, 0.061, 0.074, 0.004, 0.001, 0.012, 0.027, 
0.05, 0.01, 0.015, 0.001, 0.1, 0.079, 0.045, 0.013, 0.02, 0.001, 
0.027, 0.02, 0.019, 0.025, 0.083, 0.011, 0.039, 0.022, 0.045, 
0.012, 0.033, 0.013, 0.001, 0.001, 0.008, 0.01, 0.001, 0.159, 
0.01, 0.042, 0.018, 0.047, 0.031, 0.005, 0.015, 0.015, 0.095, 
0.024, 0.006, 0.001, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.013, 0.035, 0.153, 0.099, 
0.03, 0.043, 0.072, 0.018, 0.005, 0.001, 0.02, 0.02, 0.039, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.028, 0.015, 0.013, 0.028, 0.028, 0.022, 0.028, 
0.006, 0.001, 0.159, 0.235, 0.03, 0.06, 0.01, 0.046, 0.014, 0.003, 
0.001, 0.013, 0.027, 0.013, 0.035, 0.01, 0.072, 0.015, 0.015, 
0.002, 0.007, 0.109, 0.051, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.01, 0.21, 0.09, 
0.007, 0.035, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.013, 0.013, 0.013, 0.032, 
0.331, 0.159, 0.01, 0.051, 0.01, 0.002, 0.027, 0.001, 0.021, 
0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.018, 0.019, 0.011, 0.051, 0.205, 0.044, 
0.013, 0.035, 0.002, 0.006, 0.06, 0.021, 0.002, 0.1, 0.051, 0.042, 
0.013, 0.041, 0.013, 0.009, 0.061, 0.007, 0.052, 0.002, 0.001, 
0.026, 0.003, 0.104, 0.013, 0.011, 0.142, 0.039, 0.1, 0.091, 
0.01, 0.012, 0.006, 0.003, 0.001, 0.001, 0.049, 0.015, 0.42, 
0.013, 0.013, 0.04, 0.091, 0.011, 0.03, 0.006, 0.035, 0.035, 
0.035, 0.036, 0.027, 0.013, 0.032, 0.032, 0.128, 0.261, 0.011, 
0.035, 0.02, 0.018, 0.015, 0.015, 0.018, 0.03, 0.016, 0.035, 
0.035, 0.016, 0.004, 0.06, 0.09, 0.339, 0.011, 0.1, 0.141, 0.013, 
0.035, 0.1, 0.025, 0.018, 0.08, 0.009, 0.002, 0.011, 0.041, 0.013, 
0.007, 0.03, 0.08, 0.017, 0.215, 0.285, 0.02, 0.006, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.1, 0.012, 0.09, 0.043, 0.015, 0.015, 0.014, 0.015, 0.005, 0.035, 
0.03, 0.007, 0.015, 0.041, 0.065, 0.036, 0.008, 0.017, 0.044, 
0.002, 0.001, 0.034, 0.013, 0.007, 0.057, 0.011, 0.099, 0.081, 
0.02, 0.005, 0.04, 0.05, 0.001, 0.001, 0.02, 0.005, 0.07, 0.018, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.009, 0.004, 0.015, 0.01, 0.003, 0.012, 0.023, 
0.015, 0.017, 0.017, 0.015, 0.005, 0.058, 0.027, 0.031, 0.072, 
0.014, 0.021, 0.109, 0.055, 0.099, 0.054, 0.039, 0.015, 0.035, 
0.015, 0.035, 0.015, 0.035, 0.015, 0.035, 0.013, 0.013, 0.015, 
0.036, 0.05, 0.062, 0.006, 0.015, 0.06, 0.009, 0.037, 0.034, 
0.042, 0.012, 0.099, 0.013, 0.157, 0.063, 0.012, 0.012, 0.008, 
0.007, 0.062, 0.021)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-883L))
```

Comment: I would suggest not creating separate global variables, but you can split the data into a list. To reduce a larger dataset to only those values, you can use a `merge()` or `dplyr::inner_join()`. Then you can use `split()` to separate by group. Your example here is incomplete so it's hard to give the exact code. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I've now added some dput

Comment: Most likely `merge(df, top_5) |> split(~Code)` will do what you need. It will return a list with 5 elements each containing a data.frame with the data for a single code.

Comment: Thanks for help, one problem. The df I'm trying to filter dynamically has >1mn observations (with many many different codes), meaning merging causes some issues. Is there any way to dynamically filter, and create some fixed dataframe objects for each code from that?

Comment: Sadly the merge(df, top_5) |> split(~Code) delivers: Error: unexpected '>' in "merge(df, top_5)) |>"

Comment: What version of R are you using? The `|>` was introduced in R 4.1

Comment: R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)